# Numerical data retrieval from localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I'm working on this game, and I have encountered a problem with the saving system. When I try to save and load the game, I get the `playerLevel` as `NaN`, or not a number. I know why this is, and it's because of the output being a number within quotes. I need to know if there is any way to set a variable equal to the same variable being called back. If you don't understand my problem, here is my code:

```
function saveGame() {

    localStorage.setItem("PLAYERLEVEL", playerLevel);
    localStorage.setItem("PLAYERATTACK", Attack);
    localStorage.setItem("PLAYERDEFENSE", Defense);
    localStorage.setItem("PLAYERAGILITY", Agility);
    localStorage.setItem("PLAYERCOINS", Coins);
    localStorage.setItem("PLAYERHEALSLEFT", healsLeft);
    localStorage.setItem("PLAYERPOSSHEALS", possHealsLeft);
    localStorage.setItem("PLAYERLIVESLEFT", livesLeft);
};

function loadGame() {

    playerLevel = localStorage.getItem("PLAYERLEVEL");
    Attack = localStorage.getItem("PLAYERATTACK");
    Defense = localStorage.getItem("PLAYERDEFENSE");
    Agility = localStorage.getItem("PLAYERAGILITY");
    Coins = localStorage.getItem("PLAYERCOINS");
    healsLeft = localStorage.getItem("PLAYERHEALSLEFT");
    possHealsLeft = localStorage.getItem("PLAYERPOSSHEALS");
    livesLeft = localStorage.getItem("PLAYERLIVESLEFT");
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to retrieve a numerical data in `localStorage`, you'll need to convert the value back to a numeric value (with parseInt() or parseFloat()) to the data type you need, because `localStorage` stores everything as a string, so do this:

```
playerLevel = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('PLAYERLEVEL'));
```